# Mosquitto brocker is used for only local host?

Tags: mqtt

Can I publish and subscribe  message in mosquitto broker using ESP8266?? Mosquitto is used mainly for local host?
My requirement is , i have ESP 8266 and STM32 board. Can I use mosquitto as broker ??

Answer (score 0):

Mosquitto is a fully functional MQTT broker.

The default configuration will bind to all available interfaces on the host so it can be reached from any host on the network that knows the correct address.

Comment: How to make MQTT work with an ESP8266 WiFi module on a STM ??

Comment: That is a totally separate question